# Detach byobu screen without F6

Tags: byobu

How can I detach byobu screen without F-key. The <kbd>F6</kbd> key does not work for me (whatever problem with OSX ssh client terminal settings), is there alternative command to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

All of the standard tmux/screen escape sequences also work.

So, if your escape key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, then you can detach using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

See the manpages for [tmux](http://manpg.es/tmux) or [screen](http://manpg.es/screen) for their keybindings.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*